# Convert Java/C++ code base to an IDE based project

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, android-studio

I was wondering if it is possible to convert an existing code base (mixed - Java and C++) to an IDE (Eclipse or Android Studio) based project? The mixed code base that I have is pretty big and matured, as of today I am not using any IDE and was planning to import that code base to an IDE like Eclipse or Android Studio.

Please note that the mixed code base uses Android.mk and Application.mk files. I am thinking:

1. Create Eclipse based project and keep the mk files as is
2. Or Since Android Studio uses gradle build files instead of mk files. May be I can first create an Eclipse based project and then convert that to Android Studio based project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it.  I use Eclipse, so let's talk about that.

1. Obtain Eclipse Mars.
2. Obtain your C/C++ compiler (I use MinGW and msys, so I have to add them to the path).
3. In Eclipse go to Help ==> Install new software ==> pick Mars from the dropdown.
4. Add the CDT component to Eclipse.
5. Create a new C Project in Eclipse.
6. Save your sanity and go to builders and Project Facets and select faceted form.
7. You can create an empty C project or select Makefile Project with Existing Code.  I usually pick C project Makefile Project Empty Project and the toolchain I want to use (MinGW GCC).
8. You may need to turn off Project ==> Build automatically and change the C/C++ build command to gmake (or whatever).  In Behavior I have un-checked Build on resource save and clicked Build and clean and changed the target names to all and clean respectively.
9. Now you need to get builds working in eclipse.  Right click the project and pick build configurations, and use Build all and Clean all.
10. Now you can play with your own make files.  Personally I don't like everything slathered all in one directory so I prefer my makefiles at the root and subdirs /src /bin and /obj.  Here is a simple makefile that works in Windows or Linux and that implements 'clean' and 'all and the aforementioned structure in 33 lines:

> ```
> CC       = gcc
> # compiling flags here
> CFLAGS   = -std=c99 -Wall -I.
> # linking flags here
> LFLAGS   = -Wall -I. -lm
> LINKER   = gcc -o
> SRCDIR   = src
> OBJDIR   = obj
> BINDIR   = bin
> SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
> INCLUDES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.h)
> OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
> RM=rm -f
> TARGET = main
> ifdef ComSpec
>   EXT=.exe
> else
>   EXT=
> endif
>
> all: $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
>
> $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
>   @$(LINKER) $@ $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)
>   @echo "Linking complete!"
>
> $(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
>   @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
>   @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"
>
> clean:
>   @-$(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)$(EXT)
>   @echo "Cleanup complete!"
> ```

That should get you rolling.  Debugging should be working and you can just add in your Android specific things after you get this basic level of functionality.  If your .mk files have weird names you may need to use the command `gmake -f makefilename` to get it to be happy.

There is Gradle support for Eclipse through the Gradle Eclipse plugin from the SpringSource STS team.